# How to fetch RowId on selecting dropdown of column in JQGrid

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I have a grid with first column as DropdownList, when we select dropdown we need to get the **rowid** of selected dropdown's row.

This is what I tried :

```php
function getSelectedRowid() { 
  var grid=$(this.GridID); 
  var selectedRowID=grid.getGridParam("selrow"); 
  var oRowSpanId ="ctl00_WebPartManager_BlankWP_Control0_ctl00"; 

  $(oRowSpanId).find("input[type='text']").val(selectedRowID);
}
```

But Its returning rowid when we select the row and then on selecting dropdown, we need rowid on only selecting dropdown of the column.

Answer (score 0):

You can see [jqgrid documents](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:cell_editing) here.
you can use below function for after cell edit and get the row id:

```
 afterSaveCell: function (rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
         var rowID = rowid

 }
```

You can use the function of jqgrid as per your requirement. For Example, `loadComple()`, `beforeProcessing`,`beforeSaveCell()`